# Is there any way to express end with in Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to implement some parse function which only accept some specific character at the end of this string which would be `.*!$` if the give character is `!` using regular expression.

I have tried to use the following function, but it does not work, as it will consume characters before matching the end.

```
endWith :: Char -> Parser ()
endWith x = many anyChar >> char x >> return ()
```

One thing to note is: the expected output for `"ab!cd!"` is `("ab!cd!", "")` and `"ab!cd"` should not be consumed by this parser at all, as it is not end with `!`. The all or northing is very important when using `<|>`

Is it possible using Parsec? I suppose some advanced combination is in need.

Comment: Your given regular expression does not quite fit your specification. Remember that `*` consumes characters greedily. You want `.*?!`, which consumes the fewest possible characters until it encounters a `!`, or (my preference) `[^!]*!`, which consumes any character except `!` followed by `!`

Comment: What is the correct syntax to write `only accept some character at the end of this string`?

Comment: If you want the string to be _ended_ by the `!` you need to use `$`, which matches EOL. `[^!]*!$`

Comment: Are you looking for [__eof__](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:eof)? e.g. `endWith x = many anyChar >> char x >> eof` ?

Comment: It should not consume characters if the end character does not match. I suppose `many anyChar` would consume characters anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

endWith :: Char -> Parser String
endWith x = do cs <- many anyChar -- consume rest of input
               case cs of
                 [] -> fail "expecting !"
                 _  -> if last cs == '!' then return cs
                                         else fail "did not end in !"

test1 = parseTest (endWith '!') "This is a test!"
test2 = parseTest (endWith '!') "ab!cd!"
test3 = parseTest (endWith '!') "ab!cd"
```

Comment: What is the difference between `fail "expecting"` and `return ()`?

Comment: `return ()` succeeds with the value `()`; `fail ...` fails the parse with the given error message. if there are alternatives (i.e. created with `<|>`) then Parsec will backtrack and explore those possibilities. If there are no alternatives parsing fails with the specified message.

Comment: The manyTill solution below is more general (the last expression can be longer than a single character), simpler, and faster. Building a list and then traversing to the end of it to run a test is slow.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that successfully parses both `"ab!"` and `"ab!cd!"`, but rejects `"ab"` and `"ab!cd"`:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

endWith :: Char -> Parser String
endWith c = manyTill anyChar (try $ char c <* eof)
```

(note that the result returned doesn't include the trailing `c`):

```
"ab!"      Succeeds with "ab"
"ab!cd!"   Succeeds with "ab!cd"
"ab"       Fails
"ab!cd"    Fails
```

Answer (score 3):

[`manyTill`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:manyTill) does this.

```
endWith :: Char -> Parser String
endWith x = anyChar `manyTill` char x
```

Comment: Would it parse `ab!cd!` as `("ab!", "cd!")` or `("ab!cd!", "")`?

Comment: The former, I should think. Why don't you test it?

Comment: As my haskell envirnoment was not available at that time. it is the former one, which is not my expected one. :(